# PhpStorm: "Run with coverage" results in "Cannot load Xdebug - extension already loaded"

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I just upgraded my PhpStorm project from PHPUnit 4.x to PHPUnit 5.x. Running my unit tests works fine.

In order to get "run with coverage" working, I had to edit my Run/Debug configuration and add `--whitelist=/path/to/whitelisted/dir` to Test Runner options. Now coverage is generated when I choose "Run with coverage," but I get this Xdebug warning.

```
Testing started at 12:06 PM ...
/usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php -dzend_extension=/usr/local/opt/php56-
xdebug/xdebug.so -dxdebug.coverage_enable=1 
/Users/bwood/code/php/WpsConsole/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --
whitelist=/Users/bwood/code/php/WpsConsole/src --coverage-clover /Users/bwood/Library/Caches/PhpStorm2017.3/coverage/WpsConsole$NEW.coverage --no-configuration /Users/bwood/code/php/WpsConsole/tests/UnitTests --teamcity

Cannot load Xdebug - extension already loaded
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

I think the issue is that php is being called with

```
-dzend_extension=/usr/local/opt/php56-xdebug/xdebug.so
```

But I can't figure out where I can remove that option. I'm testing a console application so there is no webserver configuration.

Comment: Check your PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm -- there is a field for xdebug extension. It allows you to not to have xdebug loaded in actual php.ini (so the ordinary script execution will be faster) and only load xdebug when needed (debug/coverage). Based on your info so far you have it in php.ini and there. Proposed solution is to remove it from that field. Obviously, it works for CLI stuff only and dopes not affect browser based debug in any way (as it's web server that runs PHP so IDE cannot pass such params there).

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne.  I found it. It's a little buried. On MacOS: Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > PHP > CLI Interpreter > '...' (button). There I found "additional debugger extension" was set. (I've upvoted your comment.  Is there anything else I should do to give you credit here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `PHP Interpreter` in PhpStorm -- there is a separate field for xdebug extension. It allows you to not to have xdebug loaded in actual php.ini (so the ordinary script execution will be faster) and only load xdebug when needed (debug/coverage).

Based on your info so far you have it in php.ini and there. **Proposed solution is to remove it from that field.**

[image]

*P.S. Obviously, it works for CLI stuff only and dopes not affect browser based debug in any way (as it's web server that runs PHP so IDE cannot pass such parameter there).*

Comment: This fixed my issue.  I'm using WAMPServer for my dev system and I had installed xdebug in my php.ini.  I also set up my debugging extension, which I saw was being passed on the debug command line.  Removing the extension from the field removed it from the command line.

Answer (score 13):

I had two different problems that led to this same situation. (Mine was saying already loaded twice).

The first was the above debugger extension field in PHPStorm. I fixed that but was still having problems.

So then I ran:

```
>php --ini

Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

Since all of those files were in the same base directory I went to /usr/local/etc/php

```
$:/usr/local/etc/$ grep -r 'xdebug' .
./php/7.2/php.ini:zend_extension="xdebug.so"
./php/7.2/php.ini:zend_extension="xdebug.so"
```

This showed me that the problem was in my php.ini file. For some reason, I had this at the top of my php.ini file.

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
[PHP]
```

I removed one of the lines and the warning went away!

Comment: This was also the case for me. I wonder why the second line of `zend_extension="xdebug.so"` suddenly appeared in php.ini...

Comment: I think it's because some installs of xdebug automatically add this. (possibly upgrades too?) For example had this on one install: 

`|                                                                 |`
`|   NOTE: Please disregard the message |`
`|       You should add "extension=xdebug.so" to php.ini                |`
`|   that is emitted by the PECL installer. This does not work for      |`
`|   Xdebug.`